# Find div text through div label with beautifulsoup

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-3.6

Assume the following html snippet, from which I would like to extract the values corresponding to the labels 'price' and 'ships from':

```
<div class="divName">
    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <div>22.99</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ships from</label>
        <span>EU</span>
    </div>
</div>
```

Which is part of a larger html file. Assume that in some files the 'Ships from' label is present, sometimes not. I would like to use BeautifulSoup, of a similar approach, to deal with this, because of the variability of the html content. Multiple `div` and `span` are present, which makes it hard to select without id or class name

My thoughts, something like this:

```
t = open('snippet.html', 'rb').read().decode('iso-8859-1')
s = BeautifulSoup(t, 'lxml')
s.find('div.divName[label*=Price]')
s.find('div.divName[label*=Ships from]')
```

However, this returns an empty list.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `select` to find `label` and then use `find_next_sibling().text`

**Ex:**

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html = """<div class="divName">
    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <div>22.99</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ships from</label>
        <span>EU</span>
    </div>
</div>"""

soup = BeautifulSoup(html, "html.parser")
for lab in soup.select("label"):
    print(lab.find_next_sibling().text)
```

**Output:**

```
22.99
EU
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
from bs4.element import Tag

html = """ <div class="divName">
    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <div>22.99</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ships from</label>
        <span>EU</span>
    </div>
</div>"""

s = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')
row = s.find(class_='divName')
```

**Solutio-1 :**

```
for tag in row.findChildren():
    if len(tag) > 1:
        continue
    if tag.name in 'span' and isinstance(tag, Tag):
        print(tag.text)
    elif tag.name in 'div' and isinstance(tag, Tag):
        print(tag.text)
```

**Solution-2:**

```
for lab in row.select("label"):
    print(lab.find_next_sibling().text)
```

O/P:

```
22.99
EU
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `:contains` (with bs 4.7.1 and next_sibling

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs

html = '''
<div class="divName">
    <div>
        <label>Price</label>
        <div>22.99</div>
    </div>
    <div>
        <label>Ships from</label>
        <span>EU</span>
    </div>
</div>
'''

soup = bs(html, 'lxml')
items = soup.select('label:contains(Price), label:contains("Ships from")')

for item in items:
    print(item.text, item.next_sibling.next_sibling.text)
```